# MI QUERYSELECTORALL NO ME IDENTIFICA LOS BUTTON

Tags: javascript, html

Estoy intentando hacer un carrito de compras y quiero obtener los botones para así hacer la función del click en cada botón pero no me lo identifica el QuerySelectorAll('.button')

HTML

```
<div class="cursos cajabase">
            <div class="d-flex">
                <div class="col1">
                    <img src="../img/cursos/curso 7.jpg" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="col2">
                    <h4 class="fw-bold card-subtitle subtitulo">Curso de programación SQL DESDE CERO</h4>
                    <p>Aprende a programar con <b>SQL desde CERO</b>, sin conocimientos previos para poder entrar al mundo de la programación y aprender mucho más sobre SQL.</p>
                    <p class="pequeño">Jose Manuel Alarcón</p>
                    <div class="d-flex">
                        <p class="espaciadoP">5,0</p>
                        <img src="../img/Estrellas calificacion vector/5 ESTRELLAS.png" alt="" class="stars">
                        <p class="pequeño espaciadoC">(12,500)</p>
                    </div>
                    <p class="pequeño">20.5 horas en total - 16 clases - Principiante</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col3">
                    <h1>S/.149.90</h1>
                    <button class="btn btn-primary button" type="submit">Añadir al carrito</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

JS

```
const Clickbutton = document.getElementById('button')
console.log(Clickbutton)


Clickbutton.forEach(btn => {
    btn.addEventListener('click', () => console.log('button'))
})
```

Todo está linkeado y al ver la consola solo me sale esto:

```
NodeList []
length: 0
[[Prototype]]: NodeList
entries: ƒ entries()
```

Como si no existiera el button ayuda porfavor

Answer (score 0):

En principio estas tratando de seleccionar un elemento boton con **id** y no existe, debería ser mediante la clase **button**, ademas estas asignando mal el evento y quieres recorrer una constante que no es iterable, por eso el error, debería de ser así:

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".button").forEach(elem => {
  elem.addEventListener("click", e => {
    const id = e.target.getAttribute("id");
    console.log("Se ha clickeado el boton con id " + id);
  });
});
```

```html
<div class="cursos cajabase">
  <div class="d-flex">
    <div class="col1">
      <img src="../img/cursos/curso 7.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="col2">
      <h4 class="fw-bold card-subtitle subtitulo">Curso de programación SQL DESDE CERO</h4>
      <p>Aprende a programar con <b>SQL desde CERO</b>, sin conocimientos previos para poder entrar al mundo de la programación y aprender mucho más sobre SQL.</p>
      <p class="pequeño">Jose Manuel Alarcón</p>
      <div class="d-flex">
        <p class="espaciadoP">5,0</p>
        <img src="../img/Estrellas calificacion vector/5 ESTRELLAS.png" alt="" class="stars">
        <p class="pequeño espaciadoC">(12,500)</p>
      </div>
      <p class="pequeño">20.5 horas en total - 16 clases - Principiante</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col3">
      <h1>S/.149.90</h1>
      <button id="1" class="btn btn-primary button" type="submit">Añadir al carrito</button>
      <button id="2" class="btn btn-primary button" type="submit">Quitar al carrito</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Te dejo este ejemplo, donde obtengo el **id** del botón seleccionado, en este caso agregue otro para que veas que detecta el botón clickeado. Dime si te sirbio.